# Update Progress of thread in any application level WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, multithreading, .net-4.0

I dont know how to explain it .. so I decided to give image which will clear scenario.
I want to update label in my Usercontrol to get update from other thread which is started from main application. I learn dependency object help this singleton pattern lot but confused how to get it done spent almost one week :(.

Some time STA thread issue comes some time calling from other thread error occur.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of making a static class `TaskProgress` to inherit from `DependencyObject` you should implement `INotiifyPropertyChanged` in it and raise `PropertyChanged` event from the setter of the property `Instance`.

This will do the trick because of two reasons...

1. `DependencyObject` is thread agnostic and hence access to it via some other thread will surely result in error.
2. `INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged` event is internally delegated to UI dispatcher by Binding framework of WPF. So a simple `myTaskProgress.Instance = value` will update the UI automatically no matter which thread it was done from.

Note that `INotifyPropertyChanged` being an interface, it cannot be implemented on static class and cannot have static event or static property. You will hav to have some instance of `TaskProgress` (like `myTaskProgress` above) bound to the `Label`.

Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 1):

On the thread,

You can try to use this code:

```
this.Dispatcher.Invoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal, (Action)(() =>
{
    // your code to update UI here.
}
));
```

Comment: Where to use this code? and how to bind content label .. I think I am also binding wrong

Comment: if you are in no time, you could update the label from scrapAll function. Not use the TaskProgress in first moment.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the correct code should be:

```
public string lblProgressBarProducts
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(lblProgressBarProductsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(lblProgressBarProductsProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for lblProgressBarProducts.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty lblProgressBarProductsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("lblProgressBarProducts", typeof(string), typeof(TaskProgress), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));
```